# Oracle Data Pump Export - How to include a sequence with specific schema and name?

Tags: oracle

I have a parameter file for export like that:

```
schemas=SCHEMA1,SCHEMA2,SCHEMA3
include=TABLE:"IN (SELECT object_name FROM SCHEMA4.TMP_MIGRATION_EXPOBJECTS where object_type = 'TABLE')"
include=SEQUENCE:"IN (SELECT object_name FROM SCHEMA4.TMP_MIGRATION_EXPOBJECTS where object_type = 'SEQUENCE')"
```

That exports some specific objects from multiple schemas. This has been working until I had to export a sequence SCHEMA1.SEQ1. The problem is that each schema (SCHEMA1,SCHEMA2,SCHEMA3) has a sequence named "SEQ1". Currently all 3 will be exported. That makes a problem on import as we are remapping the schemas to one.

Is there a way at export to include an object with specific schema and name?

Comment: I don't know. From my point of view, why bother? In target schema, run `create sequence seq1 start with <nextval of schema1.seq1 sequence>`

Comment: If you are remapping 3 schemas into one on import, you will not be able to do what you want to do with sequences.  Use @Littlefoot idea